# For every X Y and Z element, add class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to every X, Y and Z element.

```
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(1)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(2)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(3)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(13)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(14)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(15)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(25)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(26)').addClass('rightTxt');
  $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child(27)').addClass('rightTxt');
```

As you can see my nth-child selector is targeting 1,2,3 the 13,14,15 etc elements, to which there isn't any pattern, the above works for me, im just wondering if this can be streamlined at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: put them in array and loop through the array ?

Comment: this code smells, it looks like you need some kind of refactoring first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to select every `12n + 1` (1, 13, 25), `12n + 2` (2, 14, 26) and `12n + 3` (3, 15, 27) element. So just do that:

```
$('.interactive-banner-faces')
    .children(':nth-child(12n+1), :nth-child(12n+2), :nth-child(12n+3)')
    .addClass('rightTxt');
```

Have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) to learn more about how `:nth-child` works. In short:

`n` starts from `0` and increases. So `12n + 1` will first select `12 * 0 + 1 = 1`, the first element, then `12 * 1 + 1 = 13`, the 13th element, and so on.

The selector used to "combine" the `:nth-child` selectors (`... , ... , ...`) is called the [*multiple selector*](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: Clever answer, and the cleanest one!

Comment: How does it know when to stop incrementing n? Does it use the list length, or is it as soon as it finds an undefined value it stops?

Comment: I believe it uses the list length... Bcuz if it as soon as it finds an undefined value, I believe that if one middle value for some reason would be undefined, it would just not do what it was expected to...

Comment: @judgeja: I don't know how CSS rendering is actually implemented, so I cannot give you answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var pos = [ 1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27 ];
for(i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    $('.interactive-banner-faces:nth-child(' + pos[i] + ')').addClass('rightTxt');
}
```

Another way to do this is to firstly get all the elements then get each from their position.

```
var pos = [ 1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27 ],
    $divs = $('.interactive-banner-faces');
for(i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    var $div = $($divs.get(pos[i] - 1));
    $div.addClass('rightTxt');
}
```

Note the `pos[i] - 1`, because `.get()` is zero-based.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jtYta/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function class_add(x){
    $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child('+x+')').addClass('rightTxt');
}
```

another method using `$.each()`

```
var index_1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27 ];
$.each(index_1,function class_add(i,value){
    $('.interactive-banner-faces>:nth-child('+value+')').addClass('rightTxt');
})
```